# How to replace last part of a string dynamically?

Tags: powershell

I have the following:

```
$file_input = "cube1_server1_partial.xml"
$CUBEName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file_input).ToUpper() -replace "_partial" #strips extension from $file_input
```

This results in: `cube1_server1`.

Now I have other file names that came into light, such as:

```
cube1_server1_full.xml
```

I want a comprehensive replacement that doesn't necessarily have to hard code the suffix, so instead of `-replace "_partial"`.

It should be something like `-replace "_*"` from the end of a string.

How can I have a comprehensive replace? maybe with regex?

Comment: So you want it to always remove the last `_` and everything following it?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen correct.

Comment: `$file_input -replace "_[^_]*$"` will probably work for most cases.

Comment: @AdminOfThings that works too :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the last `_` and everything following it from a string, you have a couple of options.

Use `String.LastIndexOf()` and `String.Remove()`:

```
$string = 'cube1_server1_partial'
$last_index = $string.LastIndexOf('_')
if($last_index -ne -1){
    $string = $string.Remove($last_index)
}
```

Or you could use the `-replace` regex operator with a more descriptive pattern:

```
$string = 'cube1_server1_partial'
$string -replace '(?<=.+)_[^_]*$'
```

The regex in the example above consists of:

```
(?<=  # positive look-behind assertion
  .+  # for 1 or more characters
)
_     # a literal underscore
[^_]* # any character that's NOT an underscore, 0 or more times
$     # followed by end of string
```

The look-behind ensure you don't end up with an empty string if the only `_` occurs at position 0, eg. `_partial` would just return as is. For the non-regex method the equivalent would be to check for `$last_index -gt 0` instead of `-ne -1`

Answer (score 3):

this is yet another method to get the cleaned file name. [*grin*] however, if you have *many* such items to clean up, then the regex posted by `Mathias R. Jessen` is likely your best bet for speed.

what it does ...

- split the string on the dot & save the parts into `$Name` & `$Extension`
- split the `$Name` on `_`, skip the last item, rejoin the parts with `_`
- join `$WantedNamePart` & `$Extension` with a `.`
- display the results

the code ...

```
$FileName = 'cube1_server1_partial.xml'

$Name, $Extension = $FileName.Split('.')
$WantedNamePart = ($Name.Split('_') |
    Select-Object -SkipLast 1) -join '_'

$CleanedFileName = $WantedNamePart, $Extension -join '.'

$CleanedFileName
```

output ...

```
cube1_server1.xml
```

Comment: interesting, i didnt know you can do this: $Name, $Extension =

Comment: Multi-value assignments are fun, you can even swap two variable values in one statement `$Name,$Extension = $Extension,$Name` :D

Comment: @Cataster - yep, the multiple assignment thing is occasionally quite handy. [*grin*]

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thats like replacing a variable with temp, sweet!

Answer (score 3):

Yet another solution:

```
PS> 'cube1_server1_partial.xml' -replace '(.*)_.*', '$1'
cube1_server1
```

- `(.*)_` greedily matches through the *last* `_` and captures everything before it (`.*`) in the 1st capture group (`(...)`).
- `.*` matches the rest, which ensures that the overall regex matches the entire input string.
- Replacement string `$1` then replaces the entire string with what the 1st capture group captured, which is everything before the last `_`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for more information about the `-replace` operator.